# Load facebook profile picture with greensock LoaderMax.parse

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, gsap

I am trying to load facebook profile picture but with out any succses :(

I use Greensock loaderMax to try and load it

```
private function loadProdilePicture(ImageLoaderArray:Array ):void
    {
        LoaderMax.activate([ImageLoader]);
        var queue:LoaderMax = LoaderMax.parse(ImageLoaderArray,
            {maxConnections:1, onChildComplete:onChildCompleteHandler,
                onComplete:completeHandler, onError:errorHandler,allowMalformedURL :true},
            { container:this, x:212, y:200,allowMalformedURL :true,noCache :false});
        queue.load();
    }
```

The ImageLoaderArray contain ImageLoader vars with the url's

the error I get is : 
 `Error on ImageLoader '758923107' (https://graph.facebook.com/758923107/picture?type=normal): Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/758923107/picture?type=normal&purpose=audit&gsCacheBusterID=1374335426047`

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding auditSize:false to your LoaderMax.

```
var queue:LoaderMax = LoaderMax.parse(ImageLoaderArray,
            {auditSize:false, maxConnections:1, onChildComplete:onChildCompleteHandler,
                onComplete:completeHandler, onError:errorHandler,allowMalformedURL :true},
            { container:this, x:212, y:200,allowMalformedURL :true,noCache :false});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. The strange thing is that even regular image loader don't work and it's show the same error as mention in the main question post.